# VBS doesn't complete loop when in sub, but does when not

Tags: loops, for-loop, vbscript

Long story short, I have a VBS script I'm writing with nested For loops.

If I put the code in a sub, it doesn't complete the loop. If the code is out in the main, it does. Example:

```
Do
    For x = 0 to 9
        For y = 0 to 9
            For z = 0 to 9
                want = CStr(x) & "." & CStr(y) & "." & CStr(z)
                If want = "5.1.3"
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
Loop While 1 = 1
```

If this is out in main, it works. But this:

```
NestedLoop()

Sub NestedLoop()
    Do
        For x = 0 to 9
            For y = 0 to 9
                For z = 0 to 9
                    want = CStr(x) & "." & CStr(y) & "." & CStr(z)
                    If want = "5.1.3"
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        Next
    Loop While 1 = 1
End Sub
```

Will only loop to 2.0.5

Here's the full source code for each:

[Nested Loop in Main](http://pastebin.com/C2VrGDpA)

[Nested Loop in Sub](http://pastebin.com/eEjC8nUm)

Long story short, what it does is detects the OS arch (x86 or x64), goes out to VLC's download index (https://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/last/win64/ or /win32/) and downloads to the working dir whatever version of the exe that resolves to HTTP status of 200. This also generates a log file at C:\Temp\vlc-installer.txt

So why would it not work in a sub? I know I could just have it in the main, but I'd prefer a sub.

FWIW, this is a "working interview" project. Me and another candidate for a position are tasked with coming up with an automated deployment solution.

Comment: Do you declare the variables used inside the Sub Procedure scope so you know nothing globally defined is interfering?

Comment: What is `Echo`? Are you launching the script via WSH?

Comment: @omegastripes Sorry, I should have mentioned my example was pseudocode, I'll edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your scripts have global `On Error Resume Next` statements, so I think you need to know more about how it works.
Please pay attention to the bold sentences.
From [On Error Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53f3k80h%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

> [...]
>
> Within any particular procedure, an error is not necessarily fatal as
>   long as error-handling is enabled somewhere along the call stack. **If
>   local error-handling is not enabled in a procedure and an error
>   occurs, control is passed back through the call stack until a
>   procedure with error-handling enabled is found and the error is
>   handled at that point.** If no procedure in the call stack is found to
>   have error-handling enabled, an error message is displayed at that
>   point and execution stops or the host handles the error as
>   appropriate.
>
> *On Error Resume Next* causes execution to continue with the statement
>   immediately following the statement that caused the run-time error, or
>   with the statement immediately following the most recent call out of
>   the procedure containing the On Error Resume Next statement. This
>   allows execution to continue despite a run-time error. You can then
>   build the error-handling routine inline within the procedure.
>
> **An On Error Resume Next statement becomes inactive when another
>   procedure is called, so you should execute an On Error Resume Next
>   statement in each called routine if you want inline error handling
>   within that routine.** When a procedure is exited, the error-handling
>   capability reverts to whatever error-handling was in place before
>   entering the exited procedure.
>
> [...]

In your case, when an error occurs within your sub procedure called `FindVLC`, it immediately exits (jumps to `End Sub`) then continues to work on the global scope by ignoring errors.
So, you should execute an `On Error Resume Next` statement in your sub routine if you want to ignore (or handle) errors within that as the docs say.

```
Sub FindVLC()
    On Error Resume Next
    'for loops etc.
End Sub
```

Comment: I had to check your profile to make sure it didn't point to you working at the same place I did, because I had named my sub FindVLC(). This ended up being the issue, and now works. Thanks!